# How to save the data on change of a Fragment?

Tags: android

I have multiple tabs(Fragments) in my app and on the change of one tab I want to save the data in local database so at the end I can read the data from database and generate report.. I am not able to figure out one which event I should access the data from view and write to database.. Any help please?

I am little new to this android development

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, what do you make with the local database? And Where did you stack? And show us your code, please.